# What is the proper tool to unscrew this type of screw?

Tags: travel-tools

I bought a portable stove for my travel but it broke and I tried to open it. But one of the screw looks like this. I have no idea if the manufacture put a abnormal screw. How do I unscrew this?

[image]

Comment: while it is a travel stove, you may find more support on The Great Outdoors, where more users use travel stoves while camping, hiking, etc or Home Improvement which covers screwdrivers and such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a screwdriver, not about travel.

Comment: You can also sometimes use a snake eyes bit, or get a cheap flat blade screwdriver and file a slot in it with a needle file (better screwdrivers are too hard to file, hence the cheap one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a "H-Type (notched spanner)" screw from the description below (second row from the top, second column from the right):

[image]

You will need a H-type screw driver:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a fairly common form of "tamper proof" head, you need a bit that looks like a regular flat blade but with a slot in the middle. I think it's sometimes called a "spanner head". In my experience most "[security bit sets](https://www.amazon.co.uk/FineGood-Screwdriver-Magnetic-Extension-Anti-Tamper/dp/B07K58V6R5/ref=pd_sbs_60_2/260-5167035-1350723?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07K58V6R5&pd_rd_r=57956da4-2c1e-40c0-b7c5-09679121f2a3&pd_rd_w=Dyswf&pd_rd_wg=FEcGJ&pf_rd_p=2b420a2f-6593-478e-8b5f-cb43865ff16f&pf_rd_r=00M5B6V2GNB6Z4QRC5ED&psc=1&refRID=00M5B6V2GNB6Z4QRC5ED)" contain that style of bit in a variety of sizes.